# Wamp troubles to open a particular project?

Tags: php, wamp

When i open a project done in codeignator it shows a unique action. The project opens a new window with same content as of wamp's index page.

Can Any One Help Me.All other projects are working well

Before this a server internal error was shown.And I edited apache config .And error was removed.

This Was earlier error

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: when it comes to internal server errors, reading apache log files for errors is the way to go.

Comment: forgot to add (beside apache logs) check for PHP error logs too.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic  - but now its not showing internal error. when i click on this particular project ,The project opens a new window with same content as of wamp's index page.

Comment: where do you click on to open project? Open project by entering startup page in URL bar and see if you have any errors in logs. If that works, then you might put wrong configuration in tool you use.